# Drag and Drop interface at the .net side to include tags in the document

Tags: drag-and-drop, docusignapi

Every time, we need to send different documents for vendor signature. We would like to send the documents from .net interface to Discussion.

How to add tags to each document?

Can I have a Drag and Drop interface at the .net side to include tags in the document?

Answer (score 0):

Yes have a look at the [DocuSign Dev Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) and subsequently the API Explorer and API Walkthrough Tools.  You can use the Embedded Sending flow - here is sample code for that in 6 different languages:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending

The result of the Embedded Sending API is a URL token that you can use to load the Sending View of an Envelope.